# GAE: Task on backend instance killed without warning

Tags: python, google-app-engine, timeout, backend

### TL;DR:

How can I work around this bug in Appengine: sometimes `is_shutting_down` returns False, and in a second or two, the instance is shut down?

### Details

I have a backend instance on a Google Appengine application (Python). The backend instance is used to generate reports, which sometimes takes minutes or even hours to finish.

To deal with unexpected shutdowns, I am watching for `runtime.is_shutting_down()` and store the report's intermediate state into DB when `is_shutting_down` returns True.

Here's the portion of code where I check it:

```
from google.appengine.api import runtime

#...

def my_report_function():
    #...
    # Check if we should interrupt and reschedule to avoid timeout error.
    duration_sec = time.time() - start
    too_long = MAX_SEC < duration_sec
    is_shutting_down = runtime.is_shutting_down()
    log.debug('Does this report iteration need to wrap it up soon? '
              'Too long? %s (%s sec). Shutting down? %s'
               % (too_long, duration_sec, is_shutting_down))
    if too_long or is_shutting_down:
        # save the state of report, reschedule next iteration, and return
```

Sometimes it works, but sometimes I see the following in the Appengine log:

```
D 2013-06-20 18:41:56.893 Does this report iteration need to wrap it up soon? Too long? False (348.865950108 sec). Shutting down? False 
E 2013-06-20 18:42:00.248 Process terminated because the backend took too long to shutdown.
```

Clearly, the 30-second timeout has not passed between the time when I checked the value returned by `runtime.is_shutting_down()`, and when Appengine killed the backend.

Does anybody know why this is happening, and whether there is a workaround for this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is demo code from Google IO here http://backends-io.appspot.com/

The included counter_v3_with_write_behind.py demonstrates a pattern:

On `'/_ah/start'` set a shutdown hook via

```
runtime.set_shutdown_hook(something_to_save_progress_and_requeue_task)
```

It looks like your code is 'are you shutting down right now, if not, go do something that may take a while'.  This pattern should listen for 'shut down ASAP or you lose everything'.

Comment: Thanks Monte Bel! I'll add a shutdown hook, see if that helps me avoid the problems I'm having. The demo seems to be demonstrating problems with the back-end very well. All it says is: "An error occured while contacting the counter backend."

Comment: You'd think they'd fix that.  Mercifully the link to the code seems to work  http://backends-io.appspot.com/static/counter_demo.zip  I hope it fixes your issue.